# Why doesn't the back button work when there are encoded characters in the URL?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encoding, angular-ui-router

I am new to Angular (1.5.7) and I am trying to use ui-router to route between a main page and a search results page, and change the URL to reflect the search query. Most of my queries include Chinese characters, resulting in encoded characters in the URLs, like this:

`http://localhost:3000/#/search/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87`

**My problem is this:**
When there are Chinese characters, or any other encoded characters in the URL, the back button doesn't seem to do anything.

If there are no encoded characters in the search URL (for example, if I searched for `helloWorld` or `what's_up`, the browser's (I'm using Chrome) back button works fine, and takes me back to the main page. I have tried listening for `$stateChangeStart` and `$stateChangeSuccess` events, and they do not fire only when there are encoded characters.

I have one controller for the main page which changes the URL to the search URL, and one controller for the search page which gets a result from the server. Relevant code (let me know if anything else is needed):

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {

    $scope.search = function(searchTerm) {
        if (!$scope.searchTerm || $scope.searchTerm === '') {
            return;
        }
        $window.location.href = '#/search/' + $scope.searchTerm;
        $scope.searchTerm = '';
    }

}]);

app.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $stateParams) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/search/" + $stateParams.term)
        .success(function(result) {
            $scope.entries = result;
        });
}]);

app.config([
    '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url:'/home',
                templateUrl:'/templates/home.html',
                controller: 'MainController'
            })
            .state('search', {
                url: '/search/{term}',
                templateUrl: 'templates/search.html',
                controller: 'SearchController'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
}]);
```

Can anyone explain why the back button is not working?

**Edit:** Safari displays the regular Chinese character (eg., `http://localhost:3000/#/search/中文`), and the back button works fine. So the encoded characters definitely seem to be the problem.

Comment: Can you make a quick plunker that is hard-coded to recreate it ? Are you seeing anything in the console?

Comment: [Here's a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8oVj756tUqu5bUEP79NB?p=preview). Use Chrome, type regular english into the search box. Then click the back button and it should take you back to the home page. Then try typing some Chinese like 中文. It doesn't go back.

Comment: My honest opinion is it must be something with Angular-Ui-Router, which I would recommend avoiding anyway (there really is no use for it and if you have one you are overthinking managing global state IMHO). I am not going to have time to look at that lib tonight (and frankly I don't care cause I don't like it). I will say I tried it with regular route and it worked fine https://github.com/jrgleason/simpleng1/tree/so-question (make sure that branch and type the chars into the url like http://localhost:8000/#/search/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87) This goes back fine on newest chrome.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into using ng-route. A lot of people seem to prefer ui-router so I just went with that.

Comment: A lot of people do a lot of silly things. I updated (so pull) to add an input and it seems to go back and forth just fine. If you REALLY need ui-router (or your project already uses it) I would open a bug with them (after making sure there isn't one already).

Comment: Thanks for the code example. Looks like switching to ngRoute is easier than changing the way the queries work, so I'll move to that for now.